# React HTML select element onChange function, trying to access 'event.target.value'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

When using a controlled HTML `<select>` tag in React.

About the snippet below:

Why this works:

**OPTION #1**

```
function changeSelect(event) {
  const newValue = event.target.value;
  setNestedState((prevState) => {
    return({
      ...prevState,
      propA: newValue
    });
  });
}
```

And this doesn't? (it works only on the first change)

**OPTION #2**

```
function changeSelect(event) {
  setNestedState((prevState) => {
    return({
      ...prevState,
      propA: event.target.value
    });
  });
}
```

**SNIPPET (using option #2)**

```js
function App() {
  
  const [nestedState,setNestedState] = React.useState({
    propA: 'foo1',
    propB: 'bar'
  });
  
  function changeSelect(event) {
    // const newValue = event.target.value;
    setNestedState((prevState) => {
      return({
        ...prevState,
        propA: event.target.value    // THIS DOES NOT WORK
      });
    });
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>My nested state:</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(nestedState)}</div>
      <select 
        value={nestedState.propA} 
        onChange={changeSelect}
      >
        <option value='foo1'>foo1</option>
        <option value='foo2'>foo2</option>
        <option value='foo3'>foo3</option>
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here `event` (onChange) is a `synthetic event`. `React` re-uses `synthetic event`s, which means when the function execution completes, it nullifies the `event` properties in the [`event pool`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling).

Since `setState` is `async` and `event` gets nullified after `onChange` is invoked, directly accessing event properties (i.e `event.target.value`) within the async callback won't work.

One way is to store the value from a `synthetic event` into a variable like:

```
function changeSelect(event) {
  const newValue = event.target.value; // reference
  setNestedState((prevState) => {
    return({
      ...prevState,
      propA: newValue // can use event properties
    });
  });
}
```

Another way **to make it work asynchronously** is to use `event.persist()`.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html),

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

```
function changeSelect(event) {

  event.persist();   //This will persist the event

  setNestedState((prevState) => {
    return({
      ...prevState,
      propA: event.target.value
    });
  });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ufc9va)

Comment: Hey Ravi, feel free to improve / reject my edits. good answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

As correct as ravibagul91 is, I think you are taking a convoluted route to do a relatively simple thing and you aren't really taking advantage of how state actually works.

First, are you getting anything out of having propB in the same state object as propA? From the code, it doesn't seem like it and it's not a bad idea to manage propA and propB in separate states.

That said, you can call the set method for a state directly from the select because it doesn't appear like you need to know anything about the previous state.

```
function App() {

  const [propA,setPropA] = React.useState('');
  const [propB,setPropB] = React.useState('');

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Prop A: {propA}</div>
      <div>Prop B: {propB}</div>
      <select 
        value={propA} 
        onChange={e => setPropA(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value='foo1'>foo1</option>
        <option value='foo2'>foo2</option>
        <option value='foo3'>foo3</option>
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Much easier to read, understand, and maintain IMO.