# onChange handler isn't updating state when I type in input

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My onChange handler should be setting my state with whatever I type into the input, but when I log my state afterwards, it is not getting updated.

I am not sure what to try.

```js
handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      insightsDTO: {
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
      }
    }, () => console.log(this.state, 'handle input change this.state'))
}
```

```
<div className="Form-group publish-insights-input">
  <label class="Form-label">
    URL <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
  </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="insightURL"
    placeholder="URL"
    class="Form-input"
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
    value={this.state.insightsDTO ? this.state.insightsDTO["insightURL"] : ""}
  />
</div>;
```

When I check it out on the devtools, it's setting [e.target.id] to "insightURL" and e.target.value to whatever I'm typing in, but then afterwards when I log the state, I am not seeing that e.target.value. It's still just an empty string.

Comment: Hi Annah, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React HTML select element onChange function, trying to access 'event.target.value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807849/react-html-select-element-onchange-function-trying-to-access-event-target-valu)

Answer (score 1):

Did you `bind` your change handler in the constructor?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }
```

See a full example here:

[image: Edit bind-this]

Also see React docs for controlled components: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Unrelated, also make sure to use `className` (not `class`).