# Updating deeply nested state with useState not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, use-state

I followed the answer in this thread to try to update my deeply nested object in React.
[React: Setting State for Deeply Nested Objects w/ Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798841/react-setting-state-for-deeply-nested-objects-w-hooks)

What seems to work like a charm there, will somehow break for me when doing the following:

I have a table populated with items from an array defined like so:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
{
  selected: false,
  title: 'Item 1',
  status: 'new'
},
{
  selected: false,
  title: 'Item 2',
  status: 'used'
},
]);
```

When selecting an item from that list this function gets called to update `selected` variable for the object with the index `i` like so:

```
const select = (e) => {
  const i = e.target.getAttribute('data-index');
  setItems((prevState) => {
    prevState[i].selected = !prevState[i].selected;
    return [...prevState];
  });
};
```

This will work exactly once. If I trigger `select` a second time or any time after that `return [...prevState]` somehow keeps returning the state unchanged. (`selected` stays `true` forever). I can't solve this.

`items` is attached to a component `List` like so:

```
<List
   items={items}
/>
```

and inside `List` (shortened code):

```
{items.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <tr className="list-table-tr">
          {hasSelector ? (
            <td className="list-table-td-selector">
              {item.selected ? (
                <div
                  data-index={i}
                  className="global-selector-selected"
                  onClick={select}
                ></div>
              ) : (
                <div
                  data-index={i}
                  className="global-selector-unselected"
                  onClick={select}
                ></div>
              )}
            </td>
          ) : null}
```

Comment: There **has** to be a good dupetarget for this. Anyone have one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're breaking one of the primary rules of React state: You're modifying a state object directly, rather than making a copy.

To correctly do the update, you'd do this:

```
const select = (e) => {
    const i = e.target.getAttribute('data-index');
    setItems((prevState) => {
        // Copy the array (your code was doing that)
        const update = [...prevState];
        const item = update[i];
        // Copy the object (your code wasn't doing that) and update its
        // `selected` property
        update[i] = {...item, selected: !item.selected};
        return update;
    });
};
```

Note how **both** the array **and** the object are copied, rather than just the array.

Comment: This works! I am now wondering, why the answer on the linked question is the accepted one eventhough they are also directly modifying the state directly. Anyway, thanks a ton for relieving me from my 2 hour long headache :)

Comment: Why make a copy of the entire state when only `prevState[i]` needs to be updated?

Comment: Also `select` should take an element, not a number

Comment: @smac89 - Because that's the way React works. The state member itself (`items`) has to change for React to reliably render the changed item. The `select` that was in the answer when you posted that comment is what was in the question when I answered it. The OP has since changed it.

Comment: @Pixell - The accepted answer there is, unfortunately, incorrect. It will seem to work in some cases because it's making a copy of the top-level object, but it needs to copy more than that and will not work reliably otherwise. I've [posted an answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69272573/157247) explaining that.