# how to add property to object in object array in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a state that looks like this:

```
attributes: [
{name: "capacity", items: [{ value: '256GB'},{value: '512GB'}]},
{name: 'With USB 3 ports', items: [{value: 'Yes'}, { value: 'No'}]}
]
```

I want to create a function which takes 2 paramaters, for example "capacity" and "256GB", I want to iterate over attributes state and find the object where the value property is 256GB and add another property in that object.

so I want the state to look like this:

```
attributes: [
{name: "capacity", items: [{ value: '256GB', selected: true},{value: '512GB', selected: false}]},
{name: 'With USB 3 ports', items: [{value: 'Yes'}, { value: 'No'}]}
]
```

Comment: `for (attribute in attributes) { if attribute.items[0].value == '256GB' { attribute.items.push(something) } }`

Comment: @SashaKondrashov [don't use `for...in` on an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in) and if this is stored in state don't mutate by pushing.

Comment: see: [Updating deeply nested state with useState not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270887/updating-deeply-nested-state-with-usestate-not-working-properly) and [React State update a nested array with objects based on the id when iterated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005652/react-state-update-a-nested-array-with-objects-based-on-the-id-when-iterated) for some discussion

Comment: @pilchard whoops, I could have sworn I wrote "for...of", my bad :x

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, the easiest way to do this is to use in-build javascript functions like map, and reduce as shown in the example below

Added an example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-waterfall-5dq3wo?file=/src/App.js) on how this could be achieved. The part you need to be careful is when working with objects/arrays that hold state in react, is that you do not intend to mutate them. It's out of scope for this question to explain but to get a clear understanding of it research how javascript passes parameters.